# How to remove focus in winjs listview based on borders element

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs, windows

I am made my app responsive. Suppose if I have 140 items in my listview, initially I am showing 6 items per row in full screen display, if app is resized, number of items per row might get decreased based on resized display area. Lets assume, 3 items per row.

Now what I want is, When user focus is on top row and user still presses **KEY_UP(38)**, I want to **remove focus and set it on a menu above it**, if user is on left most element in a row and still press **KEY_LEFT(37**), i want to **removes focus and set it to the menu over left**.

Now, I can add keydown event listener on listview and detect KEY_UP(38) and remove focus **only if number of items per row is stable**. But if user resizes the app, then that functionality will not work. Now, how to solve this issue.

I guess I have explained my problem correctly. Please let me know if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [XYFocus](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#xyfocus). Wire up XYFocus to listen for the arrow keys, as seen in [this sample](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#xyfocus:override):

```
WinJS.UI.XYFocus.keyCodeMap.up.push(WinJS.Utilities.Key.upArrow);
WinJS.UI.XYFocus.keyCodeMap.down.push(WinJS.Utilities.Key.downArrow);
WinJS.UI.XYFocus.keyCodeMap.left.push(WinJS.Utilities.Key.leftArrow);
WinJS.UI.XYFocus.keyCodeMap.right.push(WinJS.Utilities.Key.rightArrow);
```

I'm not sure if the ListView items are focusable. If not, add a tabindex to the item template to do so.

Let me know if that works!